# What to do if a suggested edit is "bad", but gets accepted?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I have occasionally come across suggested edits which I believe should have been rejected but were accepted (and I have voted to reject them, but was outnumbered - how dare they disagree with me!). What should one do in this case?

For example, the edit made to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359303/the-linearness-of-extended-code) changes the meaning of it. Of course, the edit may have changed the question to read what the OP *meant* to say rather than what they *did* say (my knowledge of linear codes has been lost to time, so I do not know), but I feel that the OP should still have had a say in this. On the other hand, the rest of the editing is good and should stay.

So, in the general case, what should be done? I understand that the OP gets informed of any edit, but of course if they are not a native English speaker then they might not realise the edit changes the meaning of the question. In the example above, I have left a comment pointing out the problem. Is there a better way?

Comment: You could elect to ["roll back"](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/359303/revisions) a suggested edit if deemed necessary. I have done so for this case.

Comment: @J.M. In doing so I would then be going against the democracy. I did once do this to a post, only to discover the OP linked the edit. So I was left with egg on my face.

Comment: If you can defend yourself and say the rollback was justified, why not? The problem is that some people click on approve after only a cursory glance. Actually, scratch that; some don't even glance. Oi...

Comment: Now that you brought it up: could you check and see if I did not dumbly change the question's intent with my edit?

Comment: @J.M. I gave it a cursory glace. Looks good.

Comment: (And after a more rigorous inspection, it is fine.)

Comment: In addition to rolling back, it helps to add a comment explaining why you rolled back (it seems that roll backs, unlike normal edits, cannot have a change reason included).

Comment: @Willie, sounds like a feature request is in order. :)